# convert int[2] to long

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

I have an int[2] representation of a long int in a 32 bit machine and want to convert it to long on 64bit machine. is there a safe architecture independent way of doing this conversion?

The source machine is 32bit and an int is 32bits. Destination machine is 64bit and the long long type is definitely 64bits.

can I do the following?

```
long i;
int j[2];
#ifdef LITTLEENDIAN
j[1] = *(int*)(&i);
j[0] = *(((int*)(&i))+1)
#else
j[0] = *(int*)(&i);
j[1] = *(((int*)(&i))+1)
#endif
```

If the above is incorrect, then what is the best and safest way for this? I am sure this would have been asked previously, but I didn't find a clean answer.

Thanks

Comment: It depends what you mean by "an `int[2]` representation of a `long int`".  How did you create that representation?

Comment: Endianness isn't the only issue: sizeof(int) just might equal sizeof(long) for a particular compiler on a particular machine. In that case, your code should do nothing.

Comment: For example on 64bit Windows, `long` is 32 bits.

Comment: @Steve: For any type T, sizeof(T) depends on the compiler, not the OS, so it's inaccurate to say "64bit Windows".  You'd have to say something like "Microsoft Visual C++ compiler version X.Y under Windows 7 64-bit".

Comment: Added the machine status: The source machine is 32bit and an int is 32bits. Destination machine is 64bit and the long long type is definitely 64bits.

Comment: @Kiran: But now you're asking for a platform-independent solution to a platform-specific problem!  In general, you should use `int32_t` and `int64_t` from `<stdint.h>` if you want platform-independent sized data-types.

Comment: @Paul: OK, to clarify: on 64bit Windows, for any C++ implementation which respects the OS-defined C ABI, `long` is 32 bits. It's possible to run C++ implementations which are not ABI-compatible with the OS they run under. It's not even rare, if you include implementations running in VMs, with another OS between them and the "real" host OS, but it's not what people normally mean by "C++ on 64 bit Windows".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an int[2] representation of a long int in a 32 bit machine and want to convert it to long on 64bit machine. is there a safe architecture independent way of doing this conversion?

Not really. Because apart from endianness, the sizes of the two datatypes may vary as well. On some popular platforms, `int` and `long` have the *same* size (both 32 bits)

Ultimately, it depends on how you created your `int[2]` representation. Whatever you did to create that `int` array has to be reversed in order to get a valid `long` out of it.

One approach which will work in practice (but is, technically speaking, undefined behavior), is to place both in a union:

```
union {
  int i2[2];
  long l;
} u;
```

Now you can simply write to `u.i2` and read from `u.l`. The C++ standard technically doesn't allow this (it is undefined behavior), but it is such a common trick that major compilers explicitly support it anyway.

However, a better approach might be to use a `char[]` instead of `int[]`, because `char`'s are explicitly allowed to alias other types.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. The reason why I can't use int64 directly is due to the fact that input comes from 3rd party and I dont have control over it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure of having 32-bit integer and 64-bit then you can use `union` concept.

```
union Convert
{
  long i;
  int j[2];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The width concern could be addressed by using **boost::uint64_t** on both machines.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html#boost_integer.cstdint.exact_width_integer_types